# How to distinguish a event clcik whose class exists under multiple divs

Tags: jquery

I have got two div containers (namely **TreeMenu** and **MyOrdersPage** class ) under both theses div's ,  icon-plus class  exists .
I have got a common event handler function as shown below which gets notified when clciked on icon plus under **TreeMenu** OR **MyOrdersPage**

```
$(document).on('click', '.icon-plus', function (e) {
alert('Clicked On PLUS ICON');         
});
```

How can we find  if it has been clciked from TreeMenu OR MyOrdersPage class ??  Or please let me know how to write a individual event handlers ??

http://jsfiddle.net/673h38g9/35/

Comment: there is a little bit more code on the fiddle then here :)

Comment: also there are no elements with class MyOrdersPage

Comment: @caramba , pasted wrong fiddle , updated it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.closest()` along with class selector for `TreeMenu` or`MyOrdersPage`. if object `$(this).closest('.TreeMenu')` has length greater than 0, then element is clicked from treemenu:

```
$(document).on('click', '.icon-plus', function (e) {
 if($(this).closest('.TreeMenu').length){
   alert('tree menu clicked')
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use the following code
alert((this).parent());
to get the parent div. This will return an object and you can fetch the id.

Read here:
http://api.jquery.com/parent/